# Programs look ugly with ClearLooks-Phenix theme, how to fix?

Tags: 13.04, themes, gtk, gtk3, gtk-2

Some programs on Firefox seem to become unthemed when I use ClearLooks-Phenix on Ubuntu 13.04.

This didn't happen on 12.04, and it seemed to be triggered by some update.

What could have caused it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gtk2-engines` probably became uninstalled somehow; run `sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines` to fix it.